# How can I add new models and do migrations without restarting the server manually?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

For the app I'm building I need to be able to create a new data model in models.py as fast as possible automatically.

I created a way to do this by making a seperate python program that opens models.py, edits it, closes it, and does server migrations automatically but there must be a better way.

edit: my method works on my local server but not on pythonanywhere

Comment: Probably duplicate, but your answer should be here regardless. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25477522/django-model-change-db-table-dynamically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Django documentation, I found SchemaEditor, which is exactly what you want. Using the SchemaEditor, you can create Models, delete Models, add fields, delete fields etc..

Here's an excerpt:

> Django’s migration system is split into two parts; the logic for
>   calculating and storing what operations should be run
>   (django.db.migrations), and the database abstraction layer that turns
>   things like “create a model” or “delete a field” into SQL - which is
>   the job of the SchemaEditor.

Comment: Can you point me towards the documentation you read? The one I found doesn't seem to be working correctly. I tried using the '(BaseDatabaseSchemaEditor.create_model()' function and in the docs it says that the only argument is the model but when I run it it says that I need to also pass a self argument.

Answer (score 0):

Don't rewrite your `models.py` file automatically, that is not how it's meant to work. When you need more flexibility in the way you store data, you should do the following:

- think hard about what kind of data you want to store and make your data model more abstract to fit more cases, if needed.
- Use JSON fields to store arbitrary JSON data with your model (e.g. [for the Postgres database](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#jsonfield))
- if it's not a fit, don't use Django's ORM and use a different store (e.g. Redis for key-value or MongoDB for JSON documents)

Comment: I suspect his project revolves around a cloud service which permits users to create their own tables. For that type of project, you're right, he should find other tools.