# edit Meta of db_table at runtime django

Tags: python, django, dynamic, model

I want a dynamic `django` Model to point to different db tables at run time.

What I tried is to declare the model myModel inside a view in views.py, that way i can create a model everytime i access that view and set every time a different db table (not including the model myModel in `models.py`). Doing so though, i get an error at runtime:

> RuntimeWarning: Model 'myModel' was already registered. Reloading
>   models is not advised as it can lead to inconsistencies, most notably
>   with related models.

and also i'm pretty sure this is not the way to go.

I'm assuming the best thing to do is to declare a single myModel in models.py and edit the field `db_table = 'sometable'` in the Meta class of the model but i really don't know how to achieve that. Is there an easy way to do it?

I tried to follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25477522/django-model-change-db-table-dynamically) but i didn't understand much. I don't know if this can be helpful

Thank you

Comment: Can I ask you why do you need it?

Comment: It's quite a long description but it won't really matter to the question. I just need a model to point to different db_tables at runtime, it's really that, why though it's a lot of stuff :S