# Change db_table dynamically

Tags: django, django-models

I have 7 similar tables.

I want to create a single model without set a table name. And then make my queries look to different tables depending a var name.

For example, create a Model named Customer.

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    name= models.CharField(...)

class Meta:
    managed = False
```

And then make a query like:

```
table_name = "table1"
Customer.set_table(table_name)
customers_table1 = Customer.objects.all()

table_name = "table2"
Customer.set_table(table_name)
customers_table2 = Customer.objects.all()
```

Comment: Take a look at `using(..)`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#using

Comment: Thanks Willem, but Using is to change database. But in my case its all in the same db. I want to change the table name.

Comment: Try this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/25477597/530160